# Problem coming?

Tags: battery, battery-cable

2007 Nissan Maxima. Ran some errands. Shut car off 3 different times. Started back up each time..no issues.  Get home. Shut car off. Hit button to unlock door...didnt work. Turn key over...nothing! Complete silence. No turn over of engine no clicking no dashboard lights...complete silence.
  Waited few minutes try start..started w/a noise i can only descibe was the noise car makes when "accidentally" forget car is running & turn key over . immediately shut it off.
  Again..waited try start...start fine. No noises no issues. Let it run for bit..sounded great.
  Was it a warning something is about "to go'" on car??
  (3 yrs ago replaced alternator oil pump water pump timing 
    chain. Battery replaced year ago)

Comment: I think you have already found the source of your issues in a tag you added to the question. It's the "starter".

Comment: Yeah starter i tagged for 2 different reasons..either the starter going bad..or the starter (me) was having a "moment" . Havent driven since but have started it few times w/no issues....yet. Is this something a certified mechanic would need to change?

Comment: Maybe a loose or bad connection at the battery cable(s)

Comment: Ill recheck the cables. Had that issue few yrs ago. Thought was fixed but suppose coulda came loose again.

Comment: No locks, dash lights, etc. is NOT a result of a bad starter.  It's either a cracked plate runner in the battery, or bad/loose cables.

Comment: Thanks..it was loose cable...again .Ive had it repaired a few times. I dont know why every now and again it comes loose?

Comment: My car has been running great. I went to start it a bit ago...again...nothing. Exact same issue as described above. Battery cables are tight.  Can tell me how to find if is cracked plate runner in battery or that cables are bad?